# Is the VREF pin the same as an INV pin on a DAC?

Tags: operational-amplifier, schematics, dac

I came across this schematic that connects a DAC's output and inverting pin to an external op-amp. **Most DAC's I've come across don't have inverting pins, but they have VREF pins - are these pins the same?** (I'm pretty new to using DACs)

Here is the [DAC's datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac8830-ep.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1669560715148&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fdac8830-ep)

Here is the schematic:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the data sheet you'll see this picture: -

[image]

They show two devices (8830 and 8831).

> *are these pins the same?*

No, they are not the same although there is a link between them in that the 8831 can be used to generate a bipolar output voltage (typically +/- 4.096 volts when the external op-amp is added).

> *I'm currently looking to use a DAC8050 (comment)*

[This design guide on the DAC80501](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa869/slaa869.pdf?ts=1669564438441&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) should help you produce a bipolar output: -

[image]

Comment: What is the best way to replicate this schematic without the inverting pin? Pretty new to DAC's and Op-Amps. I'm currently looking to use a DAC8050 https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac60502.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1669560620125&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.ca%252F

Comment: You won't replicate the schematic shown in your question with that DAC. However, you can add an inverting op-amp circuit and to cobble together an output that is bipolar: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa869/slaa869.pdf?ts=1669564438441&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Comment: Thx sm! Came across the same DAC80501 - will use :)

Answer (score 1):

No, INV is not the same as VREF.

Datasheet says it is the pin for junction of internal scaling resistors.

Comment: Is the inverting pin the same as the REF pin in this datasheet - https://datasheet.octopart.com/TLV5638ID-Texas-Instruments-datasheet-10254219.pdf

Comment: No reference pin will match the inv pin.